# High order DE: $y'''ctg(y')=-2(y'')^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Well $$y'''ctg(y')=-2(y'')^2$$
with the boundry conditions $$y(0)=1 \;;\;\; y'(0)=0  \;;\;\; y''(0)=1$$

As no $x$ is present in the initial DE it's safe to lower the order.

$$y'=z(y)$$ and 
$$y''=z'y'=z'z$$
$$y'''=z''z^2+z'^2z$$

And we get $$(z''z^2+z'^2z)ctg(z)+2z'^2z^2=0$$ now my problem, what do I do with the $ctg(z)$ ? How do I make this slightly nicer?

Comment: What is $ctg(x)$ ?

Comment: @Claude Liebovici $ctg(x)$=$cot(x)$=$\frac{cos(x)}{sin(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'''ctg(y')=-2(y'')^2\\
\frac{y'''}{-2y''}=\frac{y''}{ctg(y')}\\
-\frac{1}{2}\ln y''+C=\int_0^{y'} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{ctg(t)}=f(y')\\
C y''^{-1/2}=e^{f(y')}\\
C y''^{-1}=e^{2f(y')}\\
C =e^{2f(y')}y''\Leftarrow C=1  \text{ by initial condition}\\
 x+A =\int^{y'} e^{2f(t)}\,\mathrm{d}t=g(y')\\
g^{-1}(x+A)=y'\Leftarrow A=g(0)\\
y=1+\int_0^xg^{-1}(x+g(0))\,\mathrm{d}t
$$

Comment: A little tidying up to do and once I check if there are no problems you get the answer.